# Discord Audio Player

Tags: node.js

Want a bot to play a predetermined audio file when a word is written in a text channel of my personal server. Having trouble, as it is reading the message, running the code, but not finding that im in a voice channel when I really am. has permissions to join, have no idea why its not working.

Edit: New Code

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
const { waitForDebugger } = require('inspector');
var bot = new Discord.Client();
var isReady = true;
const path = require('path');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember =>{
  let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Average Bread');

  guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
  console.log('Role Assigned');
});

bot.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot is Online');
});

bot.on('message', message => {
  const args = message.content.split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  var VC = message.member.voice.channel;

  if (command === "join") {
      if (!VC) return message.reply("You are not in a voice channel.")
      VC.join()
          .then(connection => {
            message.channel.send('Joining Channel');
            var stream  = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U06jlgpMtQs')
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1});
            console.log('Joining')
          })
          .catch(console.error);
        }
  else if (command === "leave") {
  VC.leave()
    message.channel.send('Leaving channel');
    console.log('Leaving');
  }});

bot.login('token');
```

Comment: If you check the answer I've written you on your other question you'll see that I corrected that issue there.

Comment: Fixed most of the issues, just now need to get it to actually play the song. Says the bots talking but doesnt make any noise. By chance a volume variable or something I need to add? Edit: Says connection.playfile is not a function

Comment: It should be `connection.play()` but check that in the docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection)

Comment: Also, you might have the wrong path notation.

Comment: Its connecting just fine, just not playing audio. I had changed it to connection.play a few minutes ago and it still wasnt working. im 99% sure my pathing is correct.

Comment: Try moving the audio file into your bots folder and then use the relative path to it.

Comment: ok I've done that, seems to be working better but now, it joins, in log it reads that it is playing music, finishes, and leaves instantly.

Comment: Updated the code incase that helps.

Comment: tbh I have no idea why this isn't working. As far as I can tell from looking at the docs this should work just fine.